# SQL Agent shows "SQL Agent XPs Disabled" but they are not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-agent

SQL Server 2012 SP2 CU6  v-5592

I start SQL Service and SQL Agent Service; both start OK. Then I log into SSMS on Windows 2012 Ent (not R2) server and SQL Agent has red X and appears in SSMS as "SQL Agent XPs Disabled", I simply right click refresh on server in  Object Explorer and all is OK

Re-ran reconfigure  =  1 and same things; says already set to 1

Two identical servers; installed same day one does it one does not.

Why is this saying `Disabled` when it is not? Are my jobs going to fail? How do I get rid of this?

Comment: may be you should reconfigure and rerun it

Comment: https://berbagisolusi.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/enable-sql-server-agent-agent-xps-disabled/

Comment: Ran the following  several times, every time says 1  set to 1 so  is already set to = EXEC SP_CONFIGURE ‘Agent XPs’,1
 GO
 RECONFIGURE

Comment: ok then i will give you the code which i have tested and worked for me

Comment: Looks like jobs are running, I  stopped services, started again, left it showing as XPS disabled, and the job I added all ran OK

Comment: yeah but the wrong sign symbol need to turned into green by doing below practice it will get back to normal

Comment: In Sql server configuration manager, under sql server services, do you have sql server agent configured to startup automatically? Mine was set to start mode= manual, and when i changed it to automatic, it was all good.

Answer (score -2):

just execute this

```
USE MASTER DATABASE 
    declare @agent_enabled bit
    declare @show_advanced bit
    select @show_advanced = cast(value_in_use as bit)
    from sys.configurations where name = N‘show advanced options’
    select @agent_enabled = cast(value_in_use as bit)
    from sys.configurations where name = N‘Agent XPs’
    if 0 <> @agent_enabled
    begin
    if 1 <> @show_advanced
    begin
    exec sys.sp_configure @configname = N‘show advanced options’, @configvalue = 1
    reconfigure with override
    end
    exec sys.sp_configure @configname = N‘Agent XPs’, @configvalue = 0
    reconfigure with override
    if 1 <> @show_advanced
    begin
    exec sys.sp_configure @configname = N‘show advanced options’, @configvalue = 0
    reconfigure with override
    end
    end
```

---

and then go to

```
Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services (double click)->SqlServerAgent(MSSQLSERVER)-> Start(right click)
```

Comment: Well tried that, not worse off than before, it stays disabled all the time, before I just refreshed and it was green

Comment: I want agent XP to be enabled at every start uo of SQL services

Comment: "Just run this" does not tell us anything about your diagnosis of the problem or how the script fixes it.  -1